# how can i search a text file of list of words from user input and print the line which contains these words?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

My query here is I want to search words from a text file and print those lines which contain those words. All the words are given as user input.
Somehow I reached till this point it's is giving output as nothing.

```
def sip(x): 
    print("====Welcome to SIP log Debugger ==== ")
    file= input("Please Enter log File path: ")
    search = input("Enter the Errors you want to search for(seperated with commas):   ")
    search = [word.strip() for word in search.lower().split(",")]
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        line = f.readline()
        for word in line.lower().split():
            if word in line:
                print(line),
                if word == None:
                    print('')
```

Comment: `word` will never be `None`: it's a string.

Comment: Have you tried printing each word (and line) before you check if `word in line`?

Comment: def http(y):
 for line in file2:
  if re.search('401',line) or re.search('HTTP/1.1',line):
   print(line),
   if line == None:
    print('')

Answer (score 2):

You're reading all the lines and saving them into a variable:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Then you try to read one more line:

```
line = f.readline()
```

But you've already read through the whole file, so there's nothing to read anymore, thus `f.readline()` returns `''`.
Next you try to loop through each word in the `line` variable, which is just `''`.

Instead of all this, you should just loop through all the lines using `for line in f:`, so something like:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.lower()
        for word in search:
            if word in line:
                print(line)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `if word == None:`, the word can never be `None` since `line` is a string and `word` is part of that string (you used `line.split()`).

Comment: if i use the above code it prints whole file instead of lines which contain words what user gives as input.

Comment: @RAM Saw this age old answer, you should consider accepting it if it worked out for you! :)